# Random ECHO is OFF error in a call function

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

engine.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if %~1 == void goto :a1
:a1
if %~2 == 0 echo void0>void.bat
if %~2 == 1 echo void1>void.bat
goto a2
:a2
if %~1 == sm goto a3
:a3
set msg = %~2
echo %msg%
```

I open a powershell terminal for the folder engine.bat is in, I type in the following command:

```
.\engine.bat sm Hello world
```

It outputs ECHO is OFF for some reason. Any idea why?

I've tried using "echo %~2" directly instead of setting it as a variable, but it only outputs the first word. I need help!

The output I want it to be is exactly "Hello world".

Comment: In `set` statemments, use the syntax `set "var=value"`. The quotes prevent trailing spaces being included in the value assigned. There must be no spaces around the `=`. Any spaces will be included in the value assigned or the variableNAME assigned. You're setting a variable named `"msg[space]", not "msg". `msg` is thus undefined, hence `echo is off` as `echo %msg%` is resolved to just `echo`, which reports the `echo` status.

Comment: Use `if /i  "%var%"=="string"…` to compare strings. The `/i` makes the comparison case-insensitive. The quotes ensure that each side of the comparison operator `==` is non-empty and allows the strings to contain spaces.

Comment: Note that a numeric character immediately before a redirector will absorb the numeric into the command and redirect that "logical device" - 0=keyboard, 1=normal I/O, 2=error I/O, 3+ unassigned. Use the syntax `>file echo void0` to send the string `void0` to `file`.

Comment: `void` is a string, just like any other string. If you want to check whether a variablename has a value, use `if defined variablename …` For a *metavariable* like `%1` (with or without a modifier like `~?`) either assign it tto a variable for testing or use the quoted-if approach where *empty* is `""`

Comment: `%1` is the first argument (word). If you want the complete argument string, use `%*`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is falling through to the `:a1` routine even if `%1` isn’t `void`. Move the `goto :a2` to immediately after the `if %~1 == void goto :a1`.

You may also want a `goto :eof` immediately after the `if %~1 == sm goto a3`.

Comment: Not working.
`@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if %~1 == void goto :a1
goto :a2
:a1
if %~2 == 0 echo void0>void.bat
if %~2 == 1 echo void1>void.bat
:a2
if %~1 == sm goto a3
goto :eof
:a3
set msg = %~2
echo %msg%`

Answer (score 0):

`%1` would be `sm`, `%2` = `hello`, `%3` = `world`.
`%*` would be the whole arguments string: `sm hello world`, so it's also not usable.
You want to separate the first argument and "the whole rest". You can do that with a `for /f` loop:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%*") do if "%%a"=="sm" echo\%%b
```

Output with different arguments:

```
C:\Users\stephan\test>.\engine.bat

C:\Users\stephan\test>.\engine.bat sm


C:\Users\stephan\test>.\engine.bat a b c

C:\Users\stephan\test>.\engine.bat sm bc
bc

C:\Users\stephan\test>.\engine.bat sm hello beautiful world
hello beautiful world

C:\Users\stephan\test>
```